# Store Data to Firebase real time database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The data is not going to the Database. I need to send snake name and scientific name to the cloud. I am using android studio and there is no compilation error in this code, but real time database is not updated.

This my code:-

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText Snakename;
Button upload;
Spinner SciName;

DatabaseReference databaseSnake;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Snakename=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.snakeName);
    upload=(Button)findViewById(R.id.upload);
    SciName=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.scientificName);


    databaseSnake= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("snake");


    upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        addSnake();
        }
    });

 }

private void addSnake(){
    String snakename=Snakename.getText().toString().trim();
    String SCINAME=SciName.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(snakename)){
        String id=databaseSnake.push().getKey();
        Snake snake=new Snake(id,snakename,SCINAME);
        databaseSnake.child(id).setValue(snake);
        Toast.makeText(this,"Snake Added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;

    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"You Should enter a name",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
  }
}
```

and my snake class:-

```
public class Snake {

    String snakeID;
    String snakeName;
    String scientificName;
    public  Snake()
    {


    }

    public Snake(String snakeID, String snakeName, String scientificName) {
        this.snakeID = snakeID;
        this.snakeName = snakeName;
        this.scientificName = scientificName;
    }

    public String getSnakeID() {
        return snakeID;
    }

    public String getSnakeName() {
        return snakeName;
    }

    public String getScientificName() {
        return scientificName;
    }
}
```

How to check whether data is saved or not in database at runtime ??

Comment: Please attach a `ValueEventListener` to debug the error. Official doc: [ValueEventListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener)

Comment: Have you tried to add a complete listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(snakename)){
        String id=databaseSnake.push().getKey();
        Snake snake=new Snake(id,snakename,SCINAME);

        Map userInfo = new HashMap();
        userInfo.put(id, snake);
        databaseSnake.updateChildren(userInfo);

        Toast.makeText(this,"Snake Added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;

    }
```

Hope it's help full.

Answer (score 0):

as the [offical documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-completion-callback) says :

If you'd like to know when your data has been committed, you can add a completion listener. Both setValue() and updateChildren() take an optional completion listener that is called when the write has been committed to the database. If the call was unsuccessful for some reason, the listener will be passed an error object indicating why the failure occurred:

```
databaseSnake.child(id).setValue(snake, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
        if (firebaseError != null) {

      Toast.makeText(this,"Data could not be saved. " + 
      firebaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

     Toast.makeText(this,""Data saved successfully.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```